# WCF client with Client Certificate and Basic Authentication

Tags: c#, wcf-security, basic-authentication, basichttpbinding, client-certificates

I need to access web services of one of our partners.
Their services are secured with both a Client Certificate and Basic Authentication.
I'm using WCF with BasicHttpBinding.

I am able to hook up the cert using Transport level security.
I know the cert is working because I'm no longer getting a 403 error, but I am getting a 401 because I can't pass the credentials along with the transport.
From what I can see, I can only have one type of transport security scheme.

How can I achieve this?

```
<security mode="Transport">
     <transport type="Certificate" />
     <transport type="Basic" />
</security>
```

Thanks

Comment: pleas show the client-code trying to access the WCF service...

Comment: Can you clarify the service configuration. Are they using WCF? If so, could you show the web.config or the service config code?

Comment: Is the configuration using SSL (not mutual SSL) at the transport level with Basic Authentication, plus message level encryption using a client certificate?

Answer (score 3):

Did you tried to pass credential at message level.
Your config should look like:

```
<security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
</security>
```

and then in the code

```
 WebServiceProxy objClient = new WebServiceProxy ();
  objclient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "clientCert");
 objClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
 objClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "Password";
```

Comment: The question stated that he was using Basic Authenticatin - therefore transport level, rather than message level.