# How Can i access soap webservice using Client certificates in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a WCF service which uses basicHttpBinding. Now I want to secure my methods so that no one can create a proxy and use my method. I used WCF client certification from msdn. But cant move further. here is my web.config

Comment: Post (the relevant portion(s) of) the `web.config` to which you refer.  Also link to the MSDN article on WCF client certificates to which you refer.

Comment: BTW, welcome to SO!  When asking a question, try to explain what specifically you have tried - related code being best for this - and what specifically does not work (e.g. what error you get).  This will help others to help you more effectively.

Answer (score 0):

[An SO post on calling a service with a client certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8214259/1810429) explains some of what you need to know.  It is mostly from the client perspective of course, but it shows and explains some of what you will likely need.

Also check out [another SO post from the WCF service's perspective](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8214259/1810429) that should help - particularly [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/736149/1810429) that explains...

```
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate; // Assuming your BasicHttpBinding instance is called "binding".
```

...is needed on (both) the (server and) client side(s).

Finally, for some insight into accepting only certain client certificates, which is what I *think* you are after, checkout a [helpful blog post](http://architecturebyashwani.blogspot.com/2010/01/wcf-client-authentication-using-x509.html) that explains more.